# How to retrieve "${selectedElement}" from a JTable where the elements are bound to a List

Tags: java, swing, binding, javabeans

In my application I have a JTable and a List.

- **The List**:
  The list is populated using a JPA query. The user can re-execute the query by changing attributes in the GUI. Let's assume the query has a named parameter "year" and the user can change this. Then the following happens (simplified by leaving out exception handling):

  ```
  myList.clear()
  mylist.addAll( myQuery.setParameter("year", 2010) )
  ```

  As the list changes, the binding fires the required handlers and the table now reflects the new dataset.
- **The JTable**:

  The contents of the JTable come from a BeansBinding (more precisely a `JTableBinding`). The binding source is the aforementioned list.

The query is only executed for intensive tasks. Like applying a rough filter on a huge dataset. The earlier example with the year is a good example. This will always return a manageable chunk of data to the client. Now, to have a more responsive user experience, more fine-grained filters happen in the JTable itself. This avoids unnecessary round-trips to the database.

Next, assume the following scenario: A user selects a row in the table and hit's the delete button. If the table has *not* been filtered the required code is straightforward (again, no error-checking, concurrency locking, and exception handlers for code simplicity):

```
MyObject = myList.get( myTable.getSelectedRow() );
myEntityManager.getTransaction().begin()
myEntityManager.remove( myObject )
myEntityManager.getTransaction().commit()
```

**However**: If the table is filtered on the client side, the table won't reflect the data inside the List. So `getSelectedRow()` will not return an index which will map to the same entry in the List (**I have not tested this, but I beleive I am correct with this assumption?**)

### So... My question:

How best to solve this?

### A possible solution?

I've solved the problem at hand with the following:

- I created a new Bean called `selectedTableElement` which contains a member holding the element which is currently selected in the table.
- Next, I created a new binding (source: my table, target: my "selectedElement" bean) using

  ```
  binding = Bindings.createAutoBinding(UpdateStrategy.READ_WRITE, myTable, ELProperty.create("${selectedElement}"), selectedTableElement, BeanProperty.create("selectedElement"), "selectedElementBinding");
  ```

This solution effectively solves the problem by keeping track of the selected element of the table using Beans Binding.

But is this really necessary? It feels clunky to me. A whole new class only the encapsulate the selected element? Is there no other, more direct way of retrieving the `"${selectedElement}"` property of the `JTable`?

Answer (score 1):

I'll try to answer to both your questions.
Regarding the first question (the filtered selected index vs the real list index):

- I assume that you bound the table using BeansBinding, via `createJTableBinding`. So, the client-side filtering might be applied through the use of swing TableRowSorter and RowFilter. Am I right ? if so, you could use the method
  `int row = myTable.convertRowIndexToModel(myTable.getSelectedRow());`
  to convert the selected row in the filtered view to the actual selected row in the model.

For the second question (bean to keep the selected item of table)

- You could also create a binding using `this` as the source/target object, and create a property `selectedElement` in the class containing the table. Thus, you won't need another class. The code will be : `createAutoBinding(UpdateStrategy.READ_WRITE, myTable,

  ELProperty.create("${selectedElement}"), this, BeanProperty.create("selectedElement"), "selectedElementBinding");`
  (note also that READ_WRITE binding is not really used, as beans binding does not support changing the selected  element from the bound property)

Comment: This looks promising. As soon as I get around it, I'll try.